# How is DefineSection(...) used in an ASP.NET Core view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

In an ASP.NET Core 3.1 **view**, I want to know if (and how) the `DefineSection(...)` can be used to implement a section, preferably by passing in the section name as a parameter, instead of using `@section`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to know if (and how) the DefineSection(...) can be used to implement a section, "

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking for here. Sections fundamentally require a coordination between layouts and views, so dynamically including a section doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: I want to store a section name in an enum, for example, and use nameof(SectionEnum.SoAndSoSection) as the name of the section like RenderSection(nameof(SectionEnum.SoAndSoSection), false) in layout view, instead of hard-coding bare string "SoAndSoSection" section in my code. And I don't want to barely type @section SoAndSoSection in the body view. So, as regards the body view, I want to know if that's what DefineSection(...) (which takes a string parameter) is for, and an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a helper method like this:

```cs
public static class Sections
    public static void WriteMySection<T>(RazorPage<T> razorPage, string sectionName)
    {
        razorPage.DefineSection(sectionName, () =>
        {
            // here goes code that would be in a @section

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    }
```

And use it in a view in this way:

```
@{
    Sections.WriteMySection(this, "my section name");
}
```